# Usage of Android ColorPickerPalette

Tags: android, color-picker

I need to build a dialog in an Android app in which a user can select one of several pre-defined colors. I found [this color picker](http://www.materialdoc.com/color-picker/#) which suits my needs well.
The integration in the existing Android project was not a problem but I don't get it to work properly. I have to problems:

1. The dialog is shown correctly including the ColorPickerPlatte. However, I cannot change the selected color. Do I need to do this myself by using the event handler that can be passed to the init function?
2. How can I retrieve the currently selected color?

Here is what I did:

I created a layout which I set as a view for the dialog. In this view, I added a ColorPickerPalette as follows:

```
<com.android.colorpicker.ColorPickerPalette xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/color_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="16dp" />
```

In the next step I set up the dialog including the ColorPickerPalette. I do this with the following (Kotlin) code:

```
val SELECTABLE_COLORS = intArrayOf(Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.BLUE)
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_activity_form, null)
val colorPickerPalette = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.color_picker) as ColorPickerPalette
colorPickerPalette.init(SELECTABLE_COLORS.size, 4, {})
colorPickerPalette.drawPalette(SELECTABLE_COLORS, SELECTABLE_COLORS[0])
val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
dialogBuilder
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_create_activity_title)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.add, null)
return dialogBuilder.create()
```

I could not find any information the on above-linked project site. Maybe because it's too easy / obvious but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you didn't initialize the Listener. According to the [project](http://www.materialdoc.com/color-picker/#), you need to initialize a listener. `colorPickerPalette.init(colors.length, columns, mOnColorSelectedListener);`

Comment: Exactly, I didn't initialize it because I don't need to execute some logic on color change. Furthermore, I expected the plugin to handle the color change without me having to implement it. However, if I have to do it: Do you know how I have to initialize the listener?

Comment: Wouldn't you need a listener for a color change? To initialize the listener add the following to your code.
`colorPickerPalette.init(colors.length, columns, mOnColorSelectedListener);`

Comment: If I didn't miss anything, I think I do. But 1) why would I need to handle a color change myself? Everyone who uses this component then would need to write the same piece of code (=> it should be handled by the component itself). 2) What is the listener supposed to look like, i. e., how do I implement the color change?

Comment: The color change is existing in the component. All you need to do is initialize the listener. When you initialize the listener, the component then begins to implement color change in the app. If the listener is not initialized, the color change won't get implemented.

Comment: How do I initialize the listener correctly? I changed the initialization of the picker palette to: `colorPickerPalette.init(SELECTABLE_COLORS.size, 4, { color -> Toast.makeText(context, color.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()})`
It shows a Toast with the newly-selected color, however, visually the selection does not change.

Comment: Did you initialize this `mOnColorSelectedListener`?

Comment: I also tried `colorPickerPalette.mOnColorSelectedListener = ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener {  }`but that did not make a difference. It works correctly if I implement the listener as follows: `colorPickerPalette.init(SELECTABLE_COLORS.size, 4, { color -> colorPickerPalette.drawPalette(SELECTABLE_COLORS, color) })` Is that the (correct) way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you got answer the to this but I've just got out to work by using the code below.

```
colorPickerPalette.init(colors.length, 5, new ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onColorSelected(int color) {
                colorPickerPalette.drawPalette(colors, color);
                //more code
            }
        });
```